# Not sure how to use sklearn with feature vectors which contain both text and numbers

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I just started to use sklearn and I want to categorize products. The products appear on order lines and have properties like, a description, a price, a manufacturer, order quantity etc. Some of these properties are text and others are numbers (integers or floats). I want to use these properties to predict if the product needs maintenance. Products we buy can be things like engines, pumps, etc but also nuts, hoses, filters etc.
So far I did a prediction based on the price and quantity and I did other predictions based on the description or manufacturer. Now I want to combine these predictions but I'm not sure how to do that. I've seen the Pipeline and FeatureUnion pages but it is confusing to me. Does anybody have a simple example on how to predict data which has both text and number columns at the same time?

I now have:

```
order_lines.head(5)

    Part No Part Description    Quantity    Price/Base  Supplier Name   Purch UoM   Category
0   1112165 Duikwerkzaamheden   1.0 750.00  Duik & Bergingsbedrijf Europa B.V.  pcs 0
1   1112165 Duikwerkzaamheden bij de helling    1.0 500.00  Duik & Bergingsbedrijf Europa B.V.  pcs 0
2   1070285 Inspectie boegschroef, dd. 26-03-2012   1.0 0.01    Duik & Bergingsbedrijf Europa B.V.  pcs 0
3   1037024 Spare parts Albanie Acc. List   1.0 3809.16 Lastechniek Europa B.V. -   0
4   1037025 M_PO:441.35/BW_INV:0    1.0 0.00    Exalto  pcs 0

category_column = order_lines['Category']
order_lines = order_lines[['Part Description', 'Quantity', 'Price/Base', 'Supplier Name', 'Purch UoM']]

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
features_train, features_test, target_train, target_test = train_test_split(order_lines, category_column, test_size=0.20)

from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator

class FeatureTypeSelector(TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):
    FEATURE_TYPES = {
        'price and quantity': [
            'Price/Base',
            'Quantity',
        ],
        'description, supplier, uom': [
            'Part Description',
            'Supplier Name',
            'Purch UoM',
        ],
    }
    def __init__(self, feature_type):
        self.columns = self.FEATURE_TYPES[feature_type]

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.columns]

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.pipeline import make_union, make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler

preprocessor = make_union(
    make_pipeline(
        FeatureTypeSelector('price and quantity'),
        RobustScaler(),
    ),
    make_pipeline(
        FeatureTypeSelector('description, supplier, uom'),
        CountVectorizer(),
    ),
)
preprocessor.fit_transform(features_train)
```

And then I got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-f8b0db33462a> in <module>()
----> 1 preprocessor.fit_transform(features_train)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    500         self._update_transformer_list(transformers)
    501         if any(sparse.issparse(f) for f in Xs):
--> 502             Xs = sparse.hstack(Xs).tocsr()
    503         else:
    504             Xs = np.hstack(Xs)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\construct.py in hstack(blocks, format, dtype)
    462 
    463     """
--> 464     return bmat([blocks], format=format, dtype=dtype)
    465 
    466 

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\construct.py in bmat(blocks, format, dtype)
    579                 else:
    580                     if brow_lengths[i] != A.shape[0]:
--> 581                         raise ValueError('blocks[%d,:] has incompatible row dimensions' % i)
    582 
    583                 if bcol_lengths[j] == 0:

ValueError: blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions
```

Comment: just answered a very similar question . does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001956/sklearn-pipeline-transformation-on-only-certain-features

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest not to make predictions on different feature types and then combining. You're better off using `FeatureUnion` as you suggest, which allows you to create separate preprocessing pipelines for each feature type. A construction I often use is the following...

Let's define a toy example dataset to play around with:

```
import pandas as pd

# create a pandas dataframe that contains your features
X = pd.DataFrame({'quantity': [13, 7, 42, 11],
                  'item_name': ['nut', 'bolt', 'bolt', 'chair'],
                  'item_type': ['hardware', 'hardware', 'hardware', 'furniture'],
                  'item_price': [1.95, 4.95, 2.79, 19.95]})

# create corresponding target (this is often just one of the dataframe columns)
y = pd.Series([0, 1, 1, 0], index=X.index)
```

I glue everything together using `Pipeline` and `FeatureUnion` (or rather their simpler shortcuts `make_pipeline` and `make_union`):

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_union, make_pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

# create your preprocessor that handles different feature types separately
preprocessor = make_union(
    make_pipeline(
        FeatureTypeSelector('continuous'),
        RobustScaler(),
    ),
    make_pipeline(
        FeatureTypeSelector('categorical'),
        RowToDictTransformer(),
        DictVectorizer(sparse=False),  # set sparse=True if you get MemoryError
    ),
)

# example use of your combined preprocessor
preprocessor.fit_transform(X)

# choose some estimator
estimator = LogisticRegression()

# your prediction model can be created as follows
model = make_pipeline(preprocessor, estimator)

# and training is done as follows
model.fit(X, y)

# predict (preferably not on training data X)
model.predict(X)
```

Here, I defined my own custom transformers `FeatureTypeSelector` and `RowToDictTransformer` as follows:

```
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator


class FeatureTypeSelector(TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):
    """ Selects a subset of features based on their type """

    FEATURE_TYPES = {
        'categorical': [
            'item_name',
            'item_type',
        ],
        'continuous': [
            'quantity',
            'item_price',
        ]
    }

    def __init__(self, feature_type):
        self.columns = self.FEATURE_TYPES[feature_type]

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.columns]


class RowToDictTransformer(TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):
    """ Prepare dataframe for DictVectorizer """

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return (row[1] for row in X.iterrows())
```

Hope that this example paints a some clearer image of how to do feature union.

-Kris

Comment: Now I see you've removed the part about Dict

Comment: Your example gives this error: `TypeError: fit_transform() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Comment: Upvote for showing workable example. Just my 2 cents , for  categorical data , if it has limited vocab (like countries, genders) , then one-hot encoding will help. For text data like "Part Description" using average word vector is not a bad idea. Both case will give a length-fixed vector, which can be used jointly with other features.