# How do I apply one hot encoding on a pandas dataframe with both categorical and numerical features?

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, one-hot-encoding

Some features are numerical such as **"graduation rate from school"**, while other features are categorical like the **name of the school**. I used a label encoder on the features that are categorical to transform them into integers.

I now have a dataframe with both floats and integers, representing numerical features and categorical features(transformed with label encoder) respectively.

I am unsure how to proceed with a learner, do I need to use one hot encoding? And if so, how can I do so? I cannot simply pass the dataframe to the sklearn OneHotEncoder since there are floats, according to my current understanding. Do I just apply the label encoder to all features to solve the issue?

[Sample data from my dataframe. OPEID and opeid6 were transformed using a label encoder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTArn.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sklearn pipeline - how to apply different transformations on different coluns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001956/sklearn-pipeline-how-to-apply-different-transformations-on-different-coluns)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I one hot encode in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37292872/how-can-i-one-hot-encode-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the [`OneHotEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) `categorical_features` argument to select with features are categorical:

> categorical_features: “all” or array of indices or mask :
>
> Specify what features are treated as categorical.
>
> - ‘all’ (default): All features are treated as categorical.
> - array of indices: Array of categorical feature indices.
> - mask: Array of length n_features and with dtype=bool.
>
>   Non-categorical features are always stacked to the right of the matrix.