# LabelBinarizer for multiple columns in data frame

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I have a csv file which has 25 columns some are numeric and some are categorical and some are like names of actors, directors. I want use regression models on this data. In order to do so I have to convert the categorical columns string types to numeric values using LabelBinarizer from scikit package.
    How can I use LabelBinarize on this dataframe which has multiple categorical data?

[image: SampleData]

Essentially I want to binarize the labels and add them to the dataframe.

In the below code, I have retrieved the list of the columns I want to binarize not able to figure out how to add the new column back to the df?

```
categorylist = ['color', 'language', 'country', 'content_rating']
for col in categorylist:
    tempdf = label_binarizer.fit_transform(df[col])
```

In the next step, I want add the `tempdf` to `df` and drop the original column df[col].

Comment: Is `df` in your code a pandas dataframe? Please notice that the output of `sklearn` methods (like `fit_transform` in your code) is a numpy array! As such, `tempdf` in your code is not a `Pandas` dataFrame! First, you need to convert it to a dataframe (for instance `newdf = pd.DataFrame(tempdf)`) and then concat it to your `df`. Also you can delete the columns using `del df['column_name']`.
One last comment is to make sure whether you need `LableBinarizer` or `MultiLabelBinarizer`.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this in a one-liner with `pd.get_dummies`:

```
tempdf = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=categorylist)
```

Otherwise you can use a `FeatureUnion` with `FunctionTransformer` as in the answer to [sklearn pipeline - how to apply different transformations on different columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39001956/sklearn-pipeline-how-to-apply-different-transformations-on-different-columns?rq=1)

**EDIT:** As added by @dukebody in the comments, you can also use the [sklearn-pandas](https://github.com/paulgb/sklearn-pandas) package which purpose is to be able to apply different transformations to each dataframe column.

Comment: You can also use the sklearn-pandas package which purpose is to be able to apply different transformations to each dataframe column.

Comment: @dukebody this looks very handy !